# How to swap out a UIImage in a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a tableviewcell with a uiimageview whose image property is set like so in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
```

Now in `didSelectRow...` I'm trying to swap it out for its selected couterpart like so inside a switch(`indexPath.row`) :

```
case 1:
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (driveThruSelected == FALSE) {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

    }
    break;
```

The cell loads the right initial image, the first tap does indeed present the new image2.jpg, presumable over the old one.  But when I tap it again, the cell highlights blue showing it was tapped but the image (at least on top) is still the image2.jpg.

How do I remove the previous image in the image view before adding the new one?

Comment: are you toggling driveThruSelected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are setting it to FALSE the very first time the page / table loads. I believe your missing code is this driveThruSelected switching i.e.

```
case 1:
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (driveThruSelected == FALSE) {
        //set it to true
        driveThruSelected = TRUE;
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"];
    } else {
        //set it to false
        driveThruSelected = FALSE;
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];

    }
    break;
```